# Convert JavaScript to C++

Tags: javascript, c++, c, web

I have next JS code:

```
var Data = {
    result1: {
        ID1: "some text",
        ID2: "some text",
    },
    result2: {
       ID1: "some text",
       ID2: "some text",
    }
}
```

I need to find best way convert it to C++.
I am thinking about using `vector<map<string,string>> some_value`, but maybe there is some better way to do it.
So any ideas?

Comment: looks more like `map<string,map<string,string>>` to me

Comment: Yep, should be map instead vector, thanks for catch up

Answer (score 0):

to be able to process random assignments you need a bit more intelligence, since the data structure is not limited in depth (and not limited to strings).

you may look for a JSON parser, since the Part behind the "=" Sign is called JSON.

if you are limited to 2 levels of nesting and 1st level always is another record and 2nd levels always are strings than `map<string, map<string, string>>`will do it.